# I am having trouble trying to do the statistical analysis part for my bio class

Tags: r

this is my first time asking a question on here. I am tirelessly working on this lab  that was due ages ago but was able to get extended. I am not sure what I am doing anymore. I have to be able to do statistical anyalysis and do one of four tests: Correlation, Linear regression, T-test and ANOVA.

Currently what I am faced with is just getting my dataset to be readable in a wide format on R and currently what it looks like is: [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEzI6.png) I have been able to do the bare minimum which is get it read but my lesson tells me that it needs to be in a wide format and from what it looks like, it is not even in that formatting. I know I would have to run an ANOVA test as there is more than 2 categories that are being tested, but I do not know how to change variable name on the program nor do I know how to get it to run a statistical data as it is not reading the way I want it to. Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks.

edit: here's my code

```
# Statistical Data for Lab 2: Measuring Diversity 
Lab2 <- read.csv2('Lab2Measure.csv')
Lab2_wide <- Lab2
```

to which  it gives me the following output:

```
>     X.x1.y1.z1.x2.y2.z2
> 1    1,4,80,10,4,100,0
> 2      2,5,90,5,6,90,5
> 3    3,3,100,20,5,90,0
> 4      4,6,60,5,6,57,0
> 5      5,8,70,3,6,95,2
> 6      6,5,95,6,5,25,0
> 7    7,5,80,15,3,90,10
> 8     8,3,75,20,4,80,0
> 9    9,5,70,25,3,85,10
> 10    10,7,95,5,6,97,2
> 11  11,6,90,2,5,90,0.5
> 12    12,5,70,1,5,75,5
> 13   13,3,60,15,3,97,1
> 14   14,4,90,10,2,70,0
> 15    15,3,85,8,3,98,1
> 16   16,2,96,17,8,90,5
> 17   17,5,70,20,5,98,1
> 18   18,3,40,10,4,80,9
> 19   19,3,80,15,4,95,0
> 20    20,1,90,2,2,92,0
> 21    21,2,75,7,2,96,5
```

but please refer to the photo provided to understand my woes

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822  . Obviously you should be posting the code of what you have been able to do so far, but do read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 You should also respond in a timely manner or risk accumulating downvotes.

Comment: oh im sorry, I am new to this and was not aware of what i can or can't do.

Comment: fro your screenshot the data is comma-separated not semi-colon-separated, so try `read.csv`

Answer (score 3):

When you see a column name like:

```
      X.x1.y1.z1.x2.y2.z2
```

It means you didn't give the correct separator to the read function:

The default for `read.table` is whitespace. Default for `read.csv2` is semicolon. You can change the separator to be used by `read.table` with the `sep` parameter. I'm not sure that you can change the separator of `read.csv2` or `read.csv` with that parameter. I think they may throw an error if you try. As user 20650 suggests, you may get success with:

```
Lab2 <- read.csv("Lab2Measure.csv")
```

Rather than using images of datasets or the results you should learn to post the copied text from the console .

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the separator in `read.csv2()` is `;` but it seems that the separator in your data is `,`. So you should add `sep=","` to the code to make it work correctly.

```
Lab2 <- read.csv2('Lab2Measure.csv', sep=",")
```